# invalid pointer conversion C++

Tags: c++

I'm happy to post my first question here .

so i was play a little bit with pointers to understand the concept and i found this error

> error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int* pa,pb,pc,a,b,c;

    pa = &a;
    cin >> a;
    cout <<"the value of a :"<<a<<endl;
    cout <<"the value of pointer of a :"<<*pa<<endl;

// the problem begins when reading values of b :

    pb = &b; //<== error 
    cin >> b;

    cout << "the value of b : "<<b<<endl;
    cout <<"the value of pointer of b" <<*pb<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

i don't know why it went successfully with variable  `a` but failed with the same syntax in  `b` ?

EDIT : thanks for everyone , i know this question is very simple but i've learned from you :)

Comment: What type is `b`? What type is `&b`? What type is `pb`?

Comment: Sometimes it's just not worth defining multiple variables all on one line.

Comment: This leads to the question of why would you expect `pb` to be a pointer but not expect the same of `b` later on the same line. You'll probably learn something useful exploring that question for yourself.

Comment: Another reason to only declare one name per declaration and if reasonable initialize it.

Comment: Not a bad first question, by the way. Well formatted, easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common recomendation is to declare one variable per line (see for example [ES.10: Declare one name (only) per declaration](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration)), because `*` belongs to the variables, not the type and this can be confusing. Your

```
int* pa,pb,pc,a,b,c;
```

is actually

```
int* pa;
int pb;
int pc;
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

But you wanted:

```
int* pa;
int* pb;
int* pc;
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

In other words, you get the error becaue in your code `pb` is an `int` but `&b` is an `int*`. The first assignment is ok, because `pa` is a pointer.

Another common recommendation is to always initialize your variables (see [ES.20: Always initialize an object](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es20-always-initialize-an-object)), so even nicer would be

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int* pa = &a;
int* pb = &b;
int* pc = &c;
```

And once you got it straight what type `pa`, `pb` and `pc` are you can use `auto` to get "just the right type":

```
auto a = 0;     // 0 is an integer literal of type int
auto b = 0;
auto c = 0;
auto* pa = &a;  // auto would be fine too, &a is a int*
auto* pb = &b;
auto* pc = &c;
```

Comment: and with initialization it would become `auto a = 0; \n auto pa = &a;` etc.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe good point, just not sure about `auto` because given ops issue it might hide their problem

Comment: Indeed, but you already described the types so beautifully =)

Answer (score 5):

The `*` binds to the variable name, not the type.  So what you really want is:

```
int *pa,*pb,*pc,a,b,c;
```

Answer (score 5):

In the declaration

```
int* pa,pb,pc,a,b,c;
```

Only `pa` is declared as `int*`. The other variables are declared as `int`.

You would need to declare the variables as

```
int *pa, *pb, *pc, a, b, c;
```